# Why does Heroku returns Cannot GET even when the url is correct frontend and backend?

Tags: heroku, mern

In my MERN app at signup, after pressing Submit, the API sends an email to the email the user used to sign up. In that email a link is sent that should open another page with the account activation stuff. The link at signup.js in the NODE API looks like this:

```
<p>${envVars.REACT_APP_CLIENT_URL}/auth/activate/${token}</p>
```

and in the email like this:

```
https://my-app.herokuapp.com/auth/activate/some-token
```

since I set `REACT_APP_CLIENT_URL` in Heroku config vars to be `https://my-app.herokuapp.com`.

The `REACT_APP_CLIENT_URL` variable is `http://localhost:3000` in my development and all this setup works great in the development environment.

On Heroku everything works except when I open the link from inside the email.All the locations I open inside of Heroku are functioning right, but when I open a link from outside of Heroku, like from that email, it doesn't.

Might this be a mismatch between the `http` in development and `https` in production? And if so how do I tackle this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: is it a free dyno? those don't support HTTPS, altho I think it should downgrade on its own, I would try the routes through insomnia/postman and see the difference between HTTP and HTTPS, and check which routes work and which don't, could help you pinpoint where the problem is

Comment: I will sure check the routes again, but as I said, in development everything worked fine. I wonder why wouldn't work on heroku, since I added all the right environment variables

Comment: And yes, free dyno.